# How to create SRD of windows 7 on a USB disk without having a cd or dvd station?

Tags: windows-7, system-recovery

How to create a Windows 7.1 SRD on a USB disk? The system says it cannot find any cd or dvd station, which is correct. But I have a 8gb usb disk for this in the laptop..

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search would have saved you from the effort : http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/how-to-create-a-windows-rescue-usb-stick-984726

Comment: Note that this link states you need a CD/DVD drive to burn a disk. The alternative to download an ISO from a website perhaps allowed that in 2009, but now tells you to pay.

Comment: A paid solution is still a solution but you can check https://www.raymond.cc/blog/installing-windows-7-system-recovery-into-usb-flash-drive/2/ for a free alternative.

Comment: Very true, just pointing out to any one who follows the link expecting it to be possible without anything but the resources to hand.